# DBCC checkdb a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this question. Instead of performing dbcc checkdb on the live database. Can I just take the full backup and restore it in my local server and execute the dbcc checkdb on it so I would know if there are errors on the Live Database?

Comment: Because the function consumes alot of memory when performed on a live environment thats why I'm asking this. Thank you for those who will help me

Comment: Whats the point on running on standby/local server? I would suggest to take downtime on Live environment, take a backup of Live database and then run DBCC CHECKDB command. And, in case on any issues, you can restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good approach.
I will help execute DBCC CHECKDB without interruption on the live database and business work.

Sometimes in repair cases, DBCC CHECKDB causes data loss.
So, It's a very strong recommendation not to interrupt any live database.

If you find any issues in backup and restore, you can use stellar repair for MS SQL technicians. It helped me a lot in the required time.

Best of luck,